# Is it possible to create script tag without setting a scr?

Tags: javascript, html, import, module

I have a Javascript code in the string which I want to append to the HTML body. And in that code I want to `import` some functions from other localization. This is how I am appending Javascript code to the HTML body:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
script.text = await view.addScript(); // that function is returning my Javascript code
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

When I do this I am getting an error: "*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*"

Which I understand. And when I am using appending code other way:

changing:

`script.setAttribute('type', 'module');`

to

`script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');`

then I am getting and error: "*Cannot use import statement outside a module*" which I understand too.

**My question is**: is it possible to set module Javascript, where code is appended from a string, without setting a src attribute because in my case that src does not exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not fix the actual error instead? Have the server send `Content-Type: text/javascript` in the header of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. When I code this way:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
script.text = await view.addScript(); // that function is returning my Javascript code
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

What was wrong? My script text included `import` statement. When a path in `import` is incorrect then you will get a MIME error. When I gave the correct path, the error was gone and now everything is working :)